# get Unique info for a machine in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

So i have a aspx that gets IP Addresses.  but if i have multiple machines coming from an IP address I need some info that will distinguish each machine differently.

What would you use?

Comment: Are you looking for just server-side code, or a combination of client-side and server-side?

Comment: just server side code would do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a bit vague, but in most cases, I'd say cookies would do the trick (although they distinguish combinations of user, browser, and machine rather than just the machine).

Comment: what could i clarify more for you?  so that the question is not vague.  I want a bug on the clients machine to hit a aspx and jam information into my database so that i can create an analytics type approach.  I feel at a loss because if i have 2 clients behind the same router then I can not decypher the two..

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would generate a random cookie and save it on the user's browser and in a database. I could then refer to that as the machine's unique id. However, if the user clears their cookies or uses a different browser or another user logs on, the cookie will not be there. So a machine could have multiple unique ids.

This is a good question. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Call the method GUID.NewGuid and store the guid inside a session variable or cookie.

Comment: yea i thinking about that yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to get the MAC address, if you meet certain conditions.

[Get the MAC of ASP.NET website user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342738/get-the-mac-of-asp-net-website-user)

Comment: I think in this situation you have to have active x no?

Comment: I believe so, there are some major hurdles to overcome for MAC address, but it can pretty much be guaranteed unique per NIC.

Comment: I agree, but you are looking for something that would be more generally avaialble through security and what not..  So there isn't like even a Machine name that i can grab taht would make my info more unique by IP?