# How get UNIQUE values of client's machine in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, hardware, mac-address

May be it is dublicate of [get Unique info for a machine in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4099466/get-unique-info-for-a-machine-in-asp-net). But I need your other ideas for this.

Firstly let me try to explain my opinion:

I want to bind my system's user to his machine. When Admin creates a user in user role, he takes user's machine details (mac address, hardware information etc.) and when user tries to login, we check he is on valid machine or not.

With ASP.NET we can get only client values like **Machine name**, **IP Address**. But this values are changable.

How can I solve this issue? Or is there any way to get client's hardware information with ASP.NET?

Comment: How long is a piece of string? You need to build a profile or fingerprint with multiple factors built together that identifies that user. But ultimately a determined person could probably alter everything you are checking anyway. Just make it as secure as is reasonable, i.e. ROI.

Comment: To be **sure** you need to use a certificate. JS code can't really access machine details (primary because it may be a privacy problem making user tracking too easy).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti can you give more info about to use certificate, please?

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I would suggest not using MAC address as it can be easily spoofed and only ties you to the network interface, if you're user switches between wifi and wired, they would be dropped. Also, some devices - such as iPhone - are not rotating MAC addresses behind the scenes.

Can the same be achieved using a cookie - admittedly the user can delete these and will need to be reassigned, so depends how much of an issue that would be for you.

Otherwise, the only solution I have seen relies on a plugin for the user, such as Flash.

Comment: Plugin is a normal idea for think. User can create copy of cookie in any machine. Thanks for idea

Comment: No worries - mark as answer if you think it merits it :)