# Acquire client's MAC address.

Tags: asp.net, request, mac-address

Is there a fairly simple way to acquire a client's MAC address from an ASP.Net web application.

I'm 4.0 all the way, and I'm using Visual Studio 2010.

**Edits**

LISTEN!  Please do not close my issue! The one that jmccarthy linked to is not the same.  My requests are NOT coming from a web browser.  I should have been more clear.

Comment: Duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342738/get-the-mac-of-asp-net-website-user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342738/get-the-mac-of-asp-net-website-user)

Comment: @jmccarthy, Except that this doesn't help me at all, because my requests aren't coming from a web browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your requests aren't coming from a web browser, then you have to modify the client to send its MAC address. If you don't have control of the client, you're simply not getting the MAC from it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any cross-browser method of doing this short of using some sort of plugin (ActiveX).

Answer (score 0):

It's not in general possible nor meaningful, since the frames have probably passed though many routers and network equipments before getting to your server.

If you still want to do it from the server, without adding anything to your clients, here are some links with C# code to determine the MAC address from an IP Adress (you could then use ASP.NET Request variable):

[Get Mac Address](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Network/GetMacAddress.htm)

[get MAC Address of host](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxnetcom/thread/2b125a0e-f67d-476f-b8a0-a21c99279d5b/)

Be aware that this could cause heavy performance problem if you do this on standard ASP.NET request thread. You might want to do it in someasynchronous fashion.