# Need to get the clients machine name or his Mac address using asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get the MAC of ASP.NET website user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342738/get-the-mac-of-asp-net-website-user)

i am developing a local web application. I need to get the Mac id of the client PC that access the web site. The site is local so i can install some dll or library but still i need the mac address. I searched it but didn't got any solutions. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: This is impossible in the general case. The MAC address is a hardware-layer detail of the TCP stack, which is not necessary for remote computers other than the local subnet's DCHP server to know. It is in fact a security vulnerability for a client's MAC to be widely known.

You can get the IP address of a remote HTTP client using the HttpRequest instance available via the Page.Request property. If that address happens to be on the same subnet, you may be able to get the box to report its MAC address using a command-line tool, or by "sniffing" DHCP packets (which are broadcast to all computers on the network) to build your own database of MAC addresses; however this information is not made available by request with any Windows tool other than IPCONFIG (which cannot be used to interrogate other computers).